# How to measure the time it takes to receive a new sample from CODEC using a fixed sample rate of 48kHz?

Tags: stm32, dsp

in my current set up I have a CODEC set as master connected to my STM32F446RE (slave).

The current configuration utilizes I2S DMA interrupt callbacks to handle the input and processing of these samples received. The CODEC receives an external clock signal of 12.288 MHz in order to achieve a sample rate of 48 KHz.

How can I calculate the amount of time we receive every sample from the CODEC to the STM32F446?

Comment: use an oscilloscope ... change the state of a pin when sample is received

Comment: I take you mean the time it takes to receive the sample. Please edit your question to make it clear, its vague. Some may think you mean the time between one sample receive start and the next, which is obviously 1/48000 secs.

Answer (score 0):

You calculate from samples per second to seconds per sample by taking the reciprocal.

48000 samples per second is 20.833 microseconds per sample.